# Regex of sequences surrounded by specific pattern with overlapping problem

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to use python `re.finditer` to find a regex pattern but trying to make a complex pattern finding, which is the g-quadruplex motif and described as below.

1. The sequence starts with at least 3 g followed with a/t/g/c multiple times until the next group of ggg+ shows up. this will repeat 3 times and resulting in a pattern like ggg+...ggg+...ggg+...ggg+
2. The cases should be all ignored and the overlapping can show in the original sequence like ggg+...ggg+...ggg+...ggg+...ggg+...ggg+ should return 3 such patterns.

I have suffered for some time and can only find a way like:

```
re.finditer(r"(?=(([Gg]{3,})([AaTtCcGg]+?(?=[Gg]{3,})[Gg]{3,}){3}))", seq)
```

and then filter out the ones that do not with the same start position with

`re.finditer(r"([Gg]{3,})", seq)`

Is there any better way to extract this type of sequence? And no for loops please since I have millions of rows like this.
Thank you very much!

PS: an example can be like this
**gggggg**c**ggggggg**ACGCTCggctcAA**GGG**CTCC**GGG**CCCC**ggggggg**ACgcgcgAA**GGG**CTCC
1.**gggggg**c**ggggggg**ACGCTCggctcAA**GGG**CTCC**GGG**
2.**ggggggg**ACGCTCggctcAA**GGG**CTCC**GGG**CCCC**ggggggg**
3.**GGG**CTCC**GGG**CCCC**ggggggg**ACgcgcgAA**GGG**

Comment: The RE module will be using 'for loops' so why shouldn't you? Also your output examples don't seem to fit with your logic description. Perhaps you could clarify

Comment: I just don't want to use for loops outside the re function since I used it like finding ggg+ and then the rest of the pattern. And which part is not clarified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start the match, asserting that what is directly to the left is not a `g` char to prevent matching on too many positions.

To match both upper and lowercase chars, you can make the pattern case insensitive using `re.I`

The value is in capture group 1, which will be returned by re.findall.

```
(?<!g)(?=(g{3,}(?:[atc](?:g{0,2}[atc])*g{3,}){3}))
```

- `(?<!g)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `g` directly to the left
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `g{3,}` Match 3 or more `g` chars to start with
    - `(?:` Non capture group

      - `[atc](?:g{0,2}[atc])*` Optionally repeat matching `a` `t` `c` and 0, 1 or 2 g chars without crossing matching `ggg`
      - `g{3,}` Match 3 or more `g` chars to end with
    - `){3}` Close non capture group and repeat 3 times
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E0muXE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Zlp7dR)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"(?<!g)(?=(g{3,}(?:[atc](?:g{0,2}[atc])*g{3,}){3}))"
s = ("ggggggcgggggggACGCTCggctcAAGGGCTCCGGGCCCCgggggggACgcgcgAAGGGCTCC \n")
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.I))
```

Output

```
[
'ggggggcgggggggACGCTCggctcAAGGGCTCCGGG',
'gggggggACGCTCggctcAAGGGCTCCGGGCCCCggggggg',
'GGGCTCCGGGCCCCgggggggACgcgcgAAGGG'
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried and it works fine and also seems to generate the correct results for the large file. Limiting the letter before the first ggg+ is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
import regex as re

seq = 'ggggggcgggggggACGCTCggctcAAGGGCTCCGGGCCCCgggggggACgcgcgAAGGGCTCC'

for match in re.finditer(r'(?<=(^|[^g]))g{3,}([atc](g{,2}[atc]+)*g{3,}){3}', seq, overlapped=True, flags=re.I):
    print(match[0])
```

Overlapped works by restarting the search from the character after the *start* of the current match rather than the end of it. This would give you a bunch of essentially duplicate results, each just removing an extra leading G. To stop that, check for a preceding G with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=(^|[^g]))
```

The middle section needs to be a bit more complicated to require an ATC, preventing the seven G's from being split into a **ggg**g**ggg** match. So require one, then allow for any number of less the three G's followed by more ATCs; repeating as needed:

```
[atc](g{,2}[atc]+)*
```

The rest is just the Gs and the repeating.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works fine but can this write into the one that can be used for the re module directly?

Comment: If you need to use the standard library's re.finditer, use The fourth bird's pattern but select group(1) from the match. It gets around the lack of overlapping match support by returning a zero length match with a captured group from the lookahead; findall automatically uses that if there is only one group.